# getting a query value inside a map when using direct cache access

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client

How can i get the value returned from the query if i have it in the following form:

```
await weekDates.map(datee =>
   this.props.client.query({
     query:queryFetchAppEventsByDate,
     name:'fetchAppEvents',
     variables:{
       incubatorId: this.currentUser.incubator._id,
       userId: this.props.getCurrentUser.currentUser._id,
       date:datee
     }
   })

  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of promises you have to use Promise.all to get the results or do a for loop and use `await`.

The following should work

```
Promise.all(
  weekDates.map(date =>
    this.props.client.query({//assuming query returns a promise
      query: queryFetchAppEventsByDate,
      name: 'fetchAppEvents',
      variables: {
        incubatorId: this.currentUser.incubator._id,
        userId: this.props.getCurrentUser.currentUser._id,
        date: date
      }
    })
  )
).then(
  results=>console.log("results:",results)
).catch(
  error=console.log("something went wrong:",error)
);
```